# Git branching messed up

Tags: eclipse, git, github, git-branch, egit

I'm using Egit on Eclipse Mac and PC to sync a project that has three branches:

```
master
dev
rendersystem
```

I've created the project on the Mac and when I created the two branches **dev** and **rendersystem** I've used **revs/heads/master** as the Source ref and as Pull strategy I've used Merge.

Now I've switched to my PC and imported the project with Egit incl. all three branches. But if I change to **dev** or **rendersystem** branch it tells me that these branches are remotely tracked (in Branches dialog, Remote Tracking /origin/dev and /orginin/rendersystem).

If I check out **dev** or **rendersystem** branch and change my code, then commit it and try to push it to Github, it doesn't push the **dev** or **rendersystem** branches, only the **master** it pushed.

My question is now: How do I change the **dev** and **rendersystem** branches so that they are in a state where I can push them to Github from my Mac and PC?

Sorry if this question sounds confusing, but Git is one hell of confusing for beginners.

Comment: What is your refspec ? (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Push_Ref_Specifications)

Comment: Good question! I suppose you mean this: refs/heads/rendersystem? It's what I can choose in the Push dialog for Destination ref (for Source ref I can only choose refs/heads/master).

Comment: Ideally, it should be `refs/heads/* refs/heads/*`

Comment: If I click "Add All Branches Spec" it sets "Specifications to push" Source Ref & Dest Ref both to refs/heads/* but that only pushes the master, not the dev and rendersystem branches.

Comment: But if you checkout `dev`, and push (from Egit), does it push `dev`? Or do you want it to push *all* branches every time you push, whatever your current branch is?

Comment: If I checked out dev and do a push, it doesn't push dev, only master. I'd like to push whatever branch is currently checked out or has pending changes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remote tracking branches are read-only in git, as they represent remote changes. A Fetch will only update these remote tracking branches. A Pull first executes a Fetch, and then merges the changes with a locally editable branch.

On the source computer there was no need to create this branch, as it was initialized locally, and pushing the branch can create the remote branch.

You can create a local branch from the remote branches by Right clicking on the Remote branch in the Git Repositories view, and selecting Create branch... After that, your branch would be writable.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now how a local branch should be created and that it should be based on an (already existing) remote branch (I've initially created the dev branch from a local master branch which I think was wrong).